# Mongoose: Can't remove subdocument from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have UserModel defined like this :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    notes: [],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);

export { UserModel };
```

And a function that adds notes to the notes array of user

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const {
    text,
    title,
    userId,
  } = req.body;

  const currentUser = await UserModel.findById(userId);
  
  const note = new NoteModel({
    title,
    text,
  });

  currentUser.notes.push(note);
  await currentUser.save();
  res.json(currentUser);
};
```

It works correctly.
Now I want to implement deleting notes from user's notes array :

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { id: noteId } = req.params;

  const user = await UserModel.findById(req.body.userId);
  user.notes.pull(noteId);

  await user.save();
  res.json(user);
};
```

But it just doesn't delete the note.

I've tried following :

- `await user.notes.pull(noteId)`.
- (with and without awaiting)`user.notes.pull({_id: noteId)}`.
- 

```
UserModel.update( 
    { _id: userId},
    {
        $pull: {
            notes: { _id : noteId }
        }
    },
```

- Removing note using js array methods (filter, splicing, slicing and spreading)

But none of those actually removed the note.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you getting the id in `noteId`  and `userId` ?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Removing Subdocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/subdocs.html) documentation, it works fine.

E.g.

`models/user.ts`:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { NoteSchema } from "./note";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    notes: [NoteSchema],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

`models/note.ts`:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const NoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const NoteModel = mongoose.model("note", NoteSchema);
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { UserModel } from './models/user';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../src/config';

async function main() {
  mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
  db.once('open', async () => {
    // seed
    const user = new UserModel({ username: 'teresa teng', email: 'teresa.teng@example.com', password: '123456', notes: [{ title: 'a', text: 'a-text' }, { title: 'b', text: 'b-text' }] });
    await user.save();

    // query a user and remote a note
    const userDoc1 = await UserModel.findOne({ username: 'teresa teng' });
    console.log('userDoc1: ', userDoc1);
    userDoc1.notes.pull('6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0b');
    await userDoc1.save();

    // query the user and check notes
    const userDoc2 = await UserModel.findOne({ username: 'teresa teng' });
    console.log('userDoc2: ', userDoc2);
    db.close();
  })
}

main();
```

Execution logs:

```bash
userDoc1:  {
  _id: 6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0a,
  username: 'teresa teng',
  email: 'teresa.teng@example.com',
  password: '123456',
  notes: [
    {
      _id: 6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0b,
      title: 'a',
      text: 'a-text',
      createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z
    },
    {
      _id: 6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0c,
      title: 'b',
      text: 'b-text',
      createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z
    }
  ],
  createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.819Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.819Z,
  __v: 0
}
userDoc2:  {
  _id: 6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0a,
  username: 'teresa teng',
  email: 'teresa.teng@example.com',
  password: '123456',
  notes: [
    {
      _id: 6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0c,
      title: 'b',
      text: 'b-text',
      createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z
    }
  ],
  createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.819Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:13:58.452Z,
  __v: 1
}
```

package version:

```json
"mongodb": "^3.6.3",
"mongoose": "^5.11.9",
```

Comment: It works. My mistake was that I didn't put NoteSchema into notes array in UserSchema. Thanks for helping!